# unable to retrieve street,city and country by reverse geocoding using google For Australian address

Tags: c#, google-maps

I do have requirement to pull out street name, postcode, city, state, country, latitude, longitude from given address

It is working fine for Indian addresses and when I tried for Australian address, it is unable to retrieve the street name and postal code rest of the things are fine in retrieving constraints from address components which is in JSON array

I used the following code which is referred to in the Google developers forum

```
public void FrmGoogleGeoCode(string frmAddress)
{
        string addUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='" + frmAddress + "'&sensor=false";
      var result = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(addUrl);
      GoogleGeoCodeResponse test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(result);
      var response = test.results.First();  
}
```

In var result I am getting JSON array for address components and formatted address 
from the address components I had a requirement of retrieving street name, city, state, postal code and country from Australia address

Please unblock from this issue

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the addresses you're trying. Also the definition of GoogleGeoCodeResponse. When I try the following I get a valid response to street level. http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=300%20george%20st,%20sydney,%202000&sensor=false

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your response, I tried the same address i.e;300 George Street, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia but the response is no elements in the address

```
frmAddress ="300 George Street, Sydney NSW 2000, Australia";
```

This was my following code to retrieve street name,city,suburb,country,postal code

```
        string addUrl = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='" + frmAddress + "'&sensor=false";
      var result = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(addUrl);
      GoogleGeoCodeResponse test = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GoogleGeoCodeResponse>(result);
      var response = test.results.First();
      string route=null;
      string locality=null;
      string pstlCode = null;
      for (int i = 0; i < response.address_components.Count(); i++)
      {
          int j = 0;
          var components = response.address_components[i];
          string type = components.types[j].ToString();
          if (type == "route")
          {
              route = response.address_components[i].long_name.ToString();

          }
          if (type == "locality")
          {
           locality = response.address_components[i].long_name.ToString();
          }
          if (type == "postal_code")
          {
           pstlCode = response.address_components[i].long_name.ToString();
          }
      }
      frmLocation = route +","+locality +","+ pstlCode;
```

then I tried George Street, Sydney, NSW,2000, Australia with this code.

This was the following response. Please Can you just post the code so that it will help me a lot.

```
{ "results" : [ {"address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "George Street",
               "short_name" : "George Street",
               "types" : [ "colloquial_area", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "New South Wales",
               "short_name" : "NSW",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Australia",
               "short_name" : "AU",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "George Street, NSW, Australia",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.9134399,
                  "lng" : 151.1667177
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -34.0059442,
                  "lng" : 151.0332033
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : -33.9547504,
               "lng" : 151.1053691
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : -33.9134399,
                  "lng" : 151.1667177
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : -34.0059442,
                  "lng" : 151.0332033
               }
            }
         },
         "partial_match" : true,
         "types" : [ "colloquial_area", "political" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```